# Can only access one local site inside LAN from mobile device, but not the other

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I have set up two local projects on my Apache server. They are devsocialhub.com and hq.com. I have the ServerName and ServerAlias set up accordingly, enabled the sites, created the config files, the whole nine by following [this tutorial.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04) My problem is that I'm wanting to know how to access both on my mobile device while connected to my LAN. My machine is 192.168.0.101, and when I type it into my browser on my phone, only the first (devsocialhub.com) shows up.

Here is my /etc/hosts file, and the respective portions of the sites-enabled files.Ignore lazyjoe.lan. It's not being used or important right now.

Hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost HAL devsocialhub.com lazyjoe.lan hq.com


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Sites-enabled for HQ.com and devsocialhub.com

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName hq.com
ServerAlias www.hq.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/hq.com/public_html

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName devsocialhub.com
ServerAlias www.devsocialhub.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/devsocialhub.com/public_html
```

I can access them by their respective domain names just fine on the client machine, but only one works via the IP address on my phone (192.168.0.101). Here are screenshots to show they're working on the machine:

[image: HQ.com screenshot]

[image: devsocialhub.com screenshot]

How can I access both for testing on different devices? I'm not concerned with DNS, but if I have to go that route I will. I'm just unfamiliar with it.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some solution to solve this :

1. First write in your addresses in `/etc/hosts` in following format ( write your resolve names in 2 lines ) :

   Your machine Lan IP ( 192.168.0.x )   hq.com www.hq.com

   Your machine Lan IP ( 192.168.0.x )   devsocialhub.com www.devsocialhub.com
2. Check `/etc/nsswitch` file , If it resolve from file or not .
3. Did you restart your Nginx service ?

Also in your mobile try write *http://* in front of your url .

Also check `dig` command if it return the name record of both of your website if you have DNS on your server .
And your mobile should get DNS configuration from your server ( you need to setup *bind* or *named* service ) .

Comment: I'm using Apache, not nginx.

Comment: Then restart Apache !